# Controlling DAC161S997 via SPI

Tags: c, dac, msp430, iar, msp

I am using `msp-exp432p4111` devalopment board and trying to use `DAC161S997` with it.The main goal is creating a `4-20mA` according to an anolog sensor's value. But firstly i am just trying to control the output of DAC. The communication protocol is `SPI`. I have found a sample code for my DAC but it is for an msp430 chip so i have changed it for my chip. According to my debugger code works fine, i mean sending data with spi is complated but nothing happens at output(2mA always). Here is my code and connections:
[Connections](http://i.hizliresim.com/yqkkEn.jpg)
[Datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/snas621)

```
void main(void)
{
    WDT_A->CTL = WDT_A_CTL_PW | WDT_A_CTL_HOLD;     // Stop watchdog timer

    USCIB0_setupMasterSPI();
    __enable_irq();

    // Configure the DAC161S997
    Setup_DAC161  (DAC161_STD_ERR_CONFIG_MASKED, 3370, 21800);
    DAC_Error_Processing = 0;
    dacValue_mA = 4;
    dacValue = dacValue_mA * 2730;
    DAC161_Set_Out_Value_uA (dacValue);
        while(1)
    {
        // In case we extend the time between samples in the future, we will still need to keep the DAC
        // from timing out by sending a NOP command every time the loop is processed.
        DAC161_Nop();
        // Did the DAC161 indicate an error?
        if (DAC_Error_Processing)
        {
            // Perform DAC ERROR Processing Here
            DAC_Error_Processing = 0;
            dacStatus = DAC161_Read_Status();         // Read Status to clear error
        }
    }
}



const eUSCI_SPI_MasterConfig spiMasterConfig =
{
        EUSCI_B_SPI_CLOCKSOURCE_SMCLK,             // SMCLK Clock Source
        3000000,                                   // SMCLK = DCO = 3MHZ
        500000,                                    // SPICLK = 500khz
        EUSCI_B_SPI_MSB_FIRST,                     // MSB First
        EUSCI_B_SPI_PHASE_DATA_CHANGED_ONFIRST_CAPTURED_ON_NEXT,    // Phase
        EUSCI_B_SPI_CLOCKPOLARITY_INACTIVITY_HIGH, // High polarity
        EUSCI_B_SPI_3PIN                           // 3Wire SPI Mode
};
void USCIB0_setupMasterSPI(void)
{

    GPIO_setAsPeripheralModuleFunctionInputPin(GPIO_PORT_P1, GPIO_PIN5 | GPIO_PIN6 | GPIO_PIN7, GPIO_PRIMARY_MODULE_FUNCTION);
    GPIO_setAsOutputPin(GPIO_PORT_P4, GPIO_PIN0);
        SPI_initMaster(EUSCI_B0_BASE, &spiMasterConfig);                                
}

    void USCIB0_SPI_write (unsigned char *outData, unsigned char *inData, unsigned char length)
{
    unsigned char i;

    // CS Active Low
    P4->OUT ^= BIT0;
    for(i=0;i<100;i++);                     // Pause a bit

    for (i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        inData[i] = USCIB0_SPI_writeByte (outData[i]);
    }
    while (!(EUSCI_B0->IFG & EUSCI_B_IFG_TXIFG));               // USCI_B0 TX buffer ready?
    for(i=0;i<100;i++);                      // Pause a bit
    P4->OUT |= BIT0;

}

unsigned char USCIB0_SPI_writeByte (unsigned char data)
{

      while (!(SPI_getInterruptStatus(EUSCI_B0_BASE,EUSCI_B_SPI_TRANSMIT_INTERRUPT)));
      SPI_clearInterruptFlag(EUSCI_B0_BASE, SPI_getEnabledInterruptStatus(EUSCI_B0_BASE));
      SPI_transmitData(EUSCI_B0_BASE, data);
      return SPI_receiveData(EUSCI_B0_BASE);

}

void DAC161_Set_Out_Value (unsigned short value)
{
    DAC161_Write_Regs (&value, DAC161_DACCODE_REG, 2);
}

    void DAC161_Nop (void)
    {
        unsigned short deadCode = 0xdead;

        DAC161_Write_Regs (&deadCode, DAC161_NOP_REG, 2);

    }

    void Setup_DAC161 (unsigned short errConfig, unsigned short errLow_uA, unsigned short errHigh_uA)
{
    unsigned short errValue;

    DAC161_Write_Regs (&errConfig, DAC161_ERR_CONFIG_REG, 2);

    errValue = DAC161_CONVERT_ERR_VALUE(errLow_uA) & 0x7f00;;
    DAC161_Write_Regs (&errValue, DAC161_ERR_LOW_REG, 2);

    errValue = DAC161_CONVERT_ERR_VALUE(errHigh_uA) & 0xff00;;
    if (errValue < 0x80)
        errValue = 0x80;
    DAC161_Write_Regs (&errValue, DAC161_ERR_HIGH_REG, 2);

}
```

Comment: Have a look at the MSP432 example programs. And a logic analyzer would be helpful.

Comment: You would make answers easier by linking the data sheet of the DAC.